# Change Chrome cookies setting to "Allow All Cookies" using command line

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, browser, command-line

What is the command line switch should I use to select "Allow All Cookies" in Chrome? I have tried:

```
--enable-features="AllowAllCookies"
```

but it didn't work.